# How to call swift static method with escaping closure in objective-c file

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-functions

I have this static function written in swift that I need to call in objective-c file

```
static func downloadVideo(url: String, onResult: @escaping(String?) -> ()){
    //some code
    onResult("done")
}
```

In swift I would simply call it

```
Service.downloadVideo(url: "url") { (string) in
    print(string)
}
```

How should I call it in objective-c file?

EDIT:
I suppose it should look something like this?

```
[[Service new] downloadVideo:@"url" onResult:^{
    NSLog(@"success")
}];
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I need to call this function in objective c file, I set up bridging header and everything, but don't know the syntax how it should be called, when it's static and has escaping closure.

Comment: Add `@objc` to your static func. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance for calling a static method. Try this

```
[Service downloadVideo:@"url" onResult:^{
    NSLog(@"success")
}];
```